# Field Pack Fields Not Parsing in Zoo Visitor Registration Form

Tags: zoo-visitor, field-pack

After an ExpressionEngine 2.5.x to ExpressionEngine 2.8.1 upgrade, I'm running into an issue on a Zoo Visitor Registration form where Field Pack fields (previously the pre-ExpressionEngine 2.6 P&T Field Pack fields) are not rendering on the page, just the template tags themselves.

This is the template code for one field:

```
{error:member_child_relationship}
{options:member_child_relationship}
<fieldset>
  <input type="radio" id="child-relationship-{count}" name="member_child_relationship" value="{option_value}" {if option_value == 'Parent'}required{/if}>
  <label for="child-relationship-{count}">{option_value}</label>
  {if option_value == "Other"}
     <label for="child-relationship-writein" class="visuallyhidden">Write in your relationship</label>
     <input type="text" id="child-relationship-writein" name="member_child_relationship_other" >
  {/if}
</fieldset>
{/options:member_child_relationship}
```

And this is what appears on the page with the sign up form:

```
{options:member_child_relationship}  {option_value}
{/options:member_child_relationship}
```

I have the latest versions of both add-ons installed: Zoo Visitor 1.3.31 and Field Pack 2.1.1. Other fields, text and text areas, are render as expected.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? From looking at the EE 2.8.1 and the Field Pack documentation, the syntax is correct.

**UPDATE (30 March 2014)**

By moving to the stock versions of the checkbox and select fields, I was able to get things up and running again but still curious why the Field Pack equivalents  wouldn't parse...

Comment: I think this has to do with this question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24226/pt-dropdown-and-checkboxes-with-channel-forms

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly related to Visitor, i encountered the same problem in a regular Channel Form.  Not sure if the bug has already been reported to Pixel&Tonic

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Nico. I was able to get it to work by switching to the stock versions of the fields but I'll report it to P&T today.