# P&T Dropdown and Checkboxes with Channel forms

Tags: safecracker, pixelandtonic, pt-checkboxes, pt-dropdown

I have been trying to get P&T's Dropdown as well as Checkboxes to work with Channel Forms but I do not seem to have any success as of yet. I have tried using

```
    {my_field_name}
            <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_value}</option>
    {/my_field_name}
```

and

```
    {options:my_field_name}
            <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
    {/options:my_field_name}
```

and

```
    {my_field_name:options}
            <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
    {/my_field_name:options}
```

with no success. Does anyone know where i could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly got an answer from the great guys over at Pixel and Tonic. You need to add this to your expressionengine config file.

```
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_checkboxes';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_radio_buttons';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_dropdown';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_multiselect';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_pill';
```

Once that has been added to your config file, you can use P& T Dropdown with channel forms using this code

```
{options:my_field_name}
     <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_value}</option>
{/options:my_field_name}
```

and you can use the P&T Checkboxes using this code.

```
{options:my_field_name}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{my_field_name}" name="{my_field_name}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>{option_value}
    </label>
{/options:my_field_name}
```

Now I have both the dropdown and checkboxes working perfectly.

T.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the default `{field:my_field_name}` for this.

I ran into the same problem trying the add checkboxes to a form. Turns out the field doesn't hold any data, because it is in fact still empty. You can write your own custom plugin to get that data or use field:my_field_name.